# AngularJS ngTagsInput autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ng-tags-input

Here is a demo from the `ngTagsInput` website: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

When I type `tag10` in the input field, it displays a list which contains `Tag 4` through `Tag10`. Since, I have typed `Tag10` it appears in bold in the displayed list. Is there a way to display `tag10` on top of the list?

I want to achieve this functionality because when I type `tag`, it makes sense that `tag4` through `tag10` are displayed. However, when I type `tag10`, I want it to display only `tag10`. I don't see the point in displaying `tag4` through `tag9` when the user has clearly entered `tag10`.

**EDIT**

If `autocomplete` doesn't work when you click on the link I posted, click on the `Simple tags input with autocomplete` link on the same page.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't get `ngTagsInput` to work, so I used `angular-tags` to solve my problem. Here is a working plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/elPefHusJMunHEOhP0HI?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

ngTagsInput does not perform any filtering itself. It provides your application with whatever text the user has entered and it's up to your code to return a list of suggestions to be displayed. This is explained on the [getting started](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/gettingstarted) page.

That demo you mentioned simply returns a static list of tags, for the sake of simplicity. That's why the autocomplete list never changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood that `ngTagsInput` doesn't provide any filtering. So, I used `angular-tags` for my application. A plunker can be found in the update section of my question.

Comment: @Michelle Just to be clear: Although ngTagsInput itself doesn't perform any filtering, it doesn't mean that filtering out undesired results isn't possible. It only means you should provide the directive with a function that performs the filtering based on the text the user has typed.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty basic. I understand that.